# Taylor series polynomial

Tags: calculus

I got this problem but I got stuck
Prove if $f'''(a)$ exist then 
$$f'''(a)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{[3[f(a+h)-f(a-h)]-6hf'(a)]}{h^3}$$
I have tried using Taylor polynomial of degree $3$ of $f$ at $a$ and by computing at $(a+h)$ and $(a-h)$.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. Note that
$$f(a+h)=f(a)+f'(a)h+\frac{f''(a)}{2}h^2+\frac{f'''(a)}{6}h^3+o(h^3)$$
and 
$$f(a-h)=f(a)-f'(a)h+\frac{f''(a)}{2}h^2-\frac{f'''(a)}{6}h^3+o(h^3).$$
Now take the difference:
$$f(a+h)-f(a-h)=2f'(a)h+\frac{f'''(a)}{3}h^3+o(h^3).$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I was confident but I lost the track, what is the next step?

Comment: Solve for $f'''(a)$. Moreover edit you question and correct the statement.

Comment: Done I had already edited